# Flutter Error Failed to extract manifest from APK: Exit code -1073741515

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

Getting this error in android studio 3.5

Android Version 3.5

SDK 28

flutter latest version

Any one help me with this error? Getting this in windows 7 ultimate

```
Failed to extract manifest from APK: Exit code -1073741515 from: C:\Users\Shahryar Ahmed\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\29.0.2\aapt dump xmltree C:\Users\Shahryar Ahmed\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_app\build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk AndroidManifest.xml.
No application found for TargetPlatform.android_arm.
Is your project missing an android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml?
Consider running "flutter create ." to create one.
```

Answer (score 13):

Try to do a

```
flutter clean
```

This solved lots of problems for me

Comment: after flutter clean-->C:\Users\Shahryar Ahmed\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_tests\flutter_app_application>flutter clean
Deleting 'build\'.
Failed to remove build. A program may still be using a file in the directory or the directory itself. To find and stop such a program, see:
https://superuser.com/questions/1333118/cant-delete-empty-folder-because-it-is-used
FileSystemException: Deletion failed, path = 'build' (OS Error: The directory is not empty.
, errno = 145)

Comment: Have you tried to click on the link and follow the steps of the accepted answer?
Try that and then flutter clean

Answer (score 3):

From Menu Goto Tools->Flutter->Flutter Clean.
as shown in below picture.

[image: Android Studio]

Answer (score 2):

This problem happened to me .
and the error was that the **file aapt.exe** in this ( C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\29.0.2\aapt.exe) is opened by antivirus .

### the solution is : stop the antivirus and run again it will work .

also :
you can double click on aapt.exe file , if it opened by another program it will show what is this program , so you can stop or close this program and run again .

Answer (score 1):

File->Invalidate Caches/Restart..

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem and I fixed it by deleting the app.apk in the build/app/ouputs/apk directory and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Consider opening as administrator your android studio .exe

Answer (score 0):

I went through the same problem. I just uninstalled previous build in my emulator and did flutter run again... worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

After this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68142732/14409491

- I uninstalled the **antivirus**
- Then I deleted all folders in the `build-tools`  in C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools
- After that, downloaded `build-tools` again from android studio

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing this issue while using VS Code, then I tried running on Android Studio because sometimes issues are related to emulators.

Though running `flutter clean` on the terminal from the project
directory seemed to solve my problem. after that also get(pub get) your dependencies to avoid further build errors.